# AS3 AIR (ios) CameraRoll Save issue

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air, camera

Attempting to save my current MovieClip to the CameraRoll.
I have it working in another app, but am getting a blank image on this one.

Here's my code:

```
var bdToSave:BitmapData = new BitmapData(s.width * _appScale, s.height * _appScale);
bdToSave.draw(s, null, null, null, null, true);
var c:CameraRoll = new CameraRoll();
c.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSaveToCameraRoll);
c.addBitmapData(bdToSave)
```

I also tried just copying the image and adding it to stage which was also a white screen.
I know the clip (s) is there and populated though as I'm looking at the clip on screen and then click save to add it to the CameraRoll.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it should be this way :

```
if (CameraRoll.supportsAddBitmapData) {
      var c:CameraRoll = new CameraRoll();  
      cameraRoll.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSaveToCameraRoll);

      var bdToSave:BitmapData = new BitmapData(s.width * _appScale, s.height * _appScale);
      bitmapData.draw(s, null, null, null, null, true);
      c.addBitmapData(bitmapData);
 } else
   {
      trace("not supported.");
   }
```

I used this and it works fine !

Comment: It does work fine. I noticed my issue was clip was in the -xvalue and my sprite was grabbing the width/height but from 0,0 not the -x. Needed to re-compile my .swc and adjust the sprite to be at 0,0 as well and it's working perfectly.